# Sharing Webflow page on Twitter and thumbnail is missing

Tags: javascript, twitter, webflow, share-open-graph

I am trying to share a page on Twitter. My website is built using Webflow and I've set up correctly the page's open graph image.

Using the same template, the same webp images (1000px wide), and the same JS; I am getting 3 different outcomes when sharing one of my event pages.

These two outcomes below are not what I want:

[image: blank thumbnail]

[image: no thumbnail]

This is what I want:

[image: working thumbnail]

Is there any way to ensure this chosen outcome by editing the code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    let title = document.title;
    let url = window.location.href;

    $('#copyme').val(url);

    $('[data-share-facebook').attr('href', 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + url + '%2F&title=' + title + '%3F');
    $('[data-share-facebook').attr('target', '_blank');

    $('[data-share-twitter').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + url + '%2F&title=' + title + '&summary=');
    $('[data-share-twitter').attr('target', '_blank');

    $('[data-share-linkedin').attr('href', 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + url + '%2F&title=' + title + '&summary=');
    $('[data-share-linkedin').attr('target', '_blank');

    $('[data-share-email').attr('href', 'mailto:?&subject=' + title + '&body=' + url);
    $('[data-share-email').attr('target', '_blank');

    $('[data-share-whatsapp').attr('href', 'https://wa.me/?text=' + url);
    $('[data-share-whatsapp').attr('target', '_blank');
});

const viewBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-calendar1"),
    popup = document.querySelector(".popup"),
    close = popup.querySelector(".close"),
    field = popup.querySelector(".field"),
    input = field.querySelector("input"),
    copy = field.querySelector("button");

viewBtn.onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
close.onclick = () => {
    viewBtn.click();
}

copy.onclick = () => {
    input.select();
    if (document.execCommand("copy")) {
        field.classList.add("active");
        copy.innerText = "Copied";
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            field.classList.remove("active");
            copy.innerText = "Copy";
        }, 3000);
    }
}

document.querySelector('.backdrop').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    popup.classList.remove("show");
});

</script>
```

Comment: _"when sharing one of my event pages"_ - when sharing _three different_ of your event pages, it appears, according to what's visible of the shared URL in your screenshots ... Twitter has a debug tool for this, what does that say for each of these URLs?

Comment: All 3 pages give the same response:

INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  15 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully

Comment: Just want to reiterate - they are indeed 3 different pages - but each page is built using the exact same Webflow template - and just pulls the event data from a database.

Comment: Maybe twitter has an old version cached, from a situation where either the meta data was not fully present, or it could not load the image at that point? Facebook's URL debugger clears their cache, not sure if that is the same for twitter's card validator tool though.